# Android NDK use llvm-libc++ for APP_STL

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I'm trying to compile a C/C++ code that compiles on Mac using LLVM 6 (just the default of xcode) with a single c=99 flag, but in the NDK this doesn't want to compile (I get a ton of 'undefined reference to' errors).

In my Application.mk I have the APP_STL to be this:

```
APP_STL := gnustl_shared
```

At compile time, this calls this library:

```
[armeabi] Prebuilt       : libgnustl_shared.so <= <NDK>/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.8/libs/armeabi/thumb/
```

In theory (according to the docs) this APP_STL := gnustl_shared should trigger the LLVM library, which doesn't seem to be doing.

However, in the same NDK installation folder I have other libraries, which are labeled LLVM:

[image]

How can I force the APP_STL statement to use the llvm-libc++ or llvm-libc++abi library?

Edit: as requested, here's also a list of the errors I get when compiling:

[image]

Comment: May be you'd like to share some of those errors with us?

Comment: I just made an edit that includes a short list of the errors I get

Comment: 1) the error seems to be related to some `.cpp` files missing in your Application.mk (for example, the file that implements `InteractionManager::OnInteractionUpdate(...)`). 2) You can use llvm's libc by setting the value [`APP_STL := c++_shared`](http://mobilepearls.com/labs/native-android-api/ndk/docs/CPLUSPLUS-SUPPORT.html). Further, llvm-libc++ is _probably_ only supported in combination with the clang compiler

Comment: I'm trying to add the .cpp files into the manifest file, but it seems to be having issues linking almost every .cpp file, and I have over 3000 files.

How do I use the clang compiler? Just like this: NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION:=clang?

Comment: Toolchain: yes, if that doesn't work, try with an explicit version number behind it... `clang-1.2`. There is no way to help fixing your linker errors if we don't get to see them

Comment: NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION:=clang-1.2. This throws a command not found

Answer (score 0):

I think you need

```
APP_STL := c++_static
```